# When is it better to use switch/case over if statements?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, compilation

I have a tendency to use switch statements if I am creating a menu driven program, and I tend to use if statements when I only have a few items. I believe this has to do with the way I was taught in school, but I don't know if that is necessarily the way to go.

Are there vast differences between the two? When should you pick one over the other?

**Edit:** I should specify, I am mainly concerned with optimization (even if one or the other is only marginally more efficient).

Comment: Use `switch` to replace a series of `if/else if` statements that are all comparing the same expression to a constant.

Comment: IMHO, use `switch` if you could make a *jump table*.  You need to `if` statements if you are comparing against strings or ranges. A switch is easier for the compiler to translate into a jump table

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Why would the compiler not translate an if-else if series into a jump table? See https://godbolt.org/z/sqe4ea7rG

Answer (score 1):

If statements look like if statements. Switch statements look like switch statements. Some compilers may be mildly better at optimizing certain types of switch statements than the equivalent set of if statements, though that won’t be a significant factor in your situations. In cases where the two are both applicable, there are few practical concerns in choosing one over the other.

Use whichever fits your intended coding style better.

Comment: I support the spirit of this answer, which I read as "don't prematurely optimize". But aside from that, the rest of the answer reads as "use if statements in situations where if statements make sense", which is tautological. Perhaps the answer would benefit from some slightly more concrete advice, from a coding style perspective.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo if the two don’t *feel* different to the person (in a particular situation), there is no reason to pick one or the other. If they *do* feel different,  then the question is answered intuitively — as long as the person  doesn’t have to worry that there are unexpected considerations. The spirit of the answer, I would say, is “don’t worry”. “Don’t prematurely optimize” is only one facet of it.

Comment: @Sneftel I think you might be misunderstanding where I am coming from, and I think you're quick to assume that, "that won't be a significant factor in your situations". I am most certainly interested in the "practical concerns" in choosing one or the other.

Comment: @MisplacedSoutherner If you're asking the question, rather than analyzing the generated assembly, then you're not at the point where your code is so tightly optimized that any performance difference between the two would be significant. The if/switch thing doesn't matter. Concentrate on what matters.